# Multiple category id wise show product in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship, categories

I am trying to building ecoommerce system using laravel 9. Everything goes fine but Suddenly I got one issue. I want to show product based on category id but my product table category id store multiple. Bellow I am showing my table structure:

### Product Table:

```
|---ID---|---Name---|---Cat_id---|---Status--|
|   1    | T-shirts |    1,2,    |   active  |
|   2    | Pants    |    4,3,    |   active  |
|   3    | Sweaters |    5,2,    |   active  |
```

### Category Table

```
|---ID---|---Name---|
|   1    | General  |
|   2    | News     |
|   3    | Festival |
|   4    | Category |
```

### Controller

```
public function category($slug)
{
    //
    $cat = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $products = Product::whereIn('cat_id', [$cat->id])->where('status', 'active')->orderby('id', 'asc')->paginate('12');

    return view('frontend/Catproducts', compact('products', 'cat'));
}
```

**Now I want when I am click on "NEWS" category I want to see two product. How can I fix it**

Comment: Normalize your database. You need a pivot table with `product_id` and `category_id`, with a `hasMany` relationship.  See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aynber said in the comments, best solution is to normalize the database, so you have a setup like this:

Categories table:

- id
- name

Products table:

- id
- name
- status

Product_categories table:

- id
- product_id
- category_id

With a [belongsToMany relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) from Product to Category(and back), your query should look something like:

```
$categoryIdArray = [2];
Product
    ::whereHas('category', function($query) use($categoryIdArray) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $categoryIdArray);
    })
    ->get();
```

It is still possible with your current setup though, while a little hacky:

```
$cat = Category
    ::where('slug', $slug)
    ->first();
$catId = $cat->id;
$products = Product
    ::where(function($where) {
        $where->where('cat_id', 'like', "$catId,%")//Look for first cat in col, don't forget trailing comma
            ->orWhere('cat_id', 'like', "%,$catId,%")//Look for appended cat between commas
    })
    ->where('status', 'active')
    ->orderby('id', 'asc')
    ->paginate('12');
```

This will work on small scale, but because we are using `like`, mysql needs to check ALL records, and cannot optimize the query. That's the reason why normalization is important :)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the feedback. It was a mistake indeed. We use products with `category_id` in our DB, so me putting it there was more a brainfart :) I mean it works fine for us, but then our categories are recursively connected with a `parent_id` to `id`, so we only need 1 `category_id` per product.

Comment: No worries! I figured it was something like that  Thanks for fixing! Sidenote, I actually use the same `id | parent_id` for recursive `category` relationships in one of my projects; love the implementation!