# Transform the DB to Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Good day to all laravel dev;**

I created a joining table in my controller but, it's to long, is there's a way to recreate this query in eloquent relationship? I tried many tutorials but no luck for me, or any better solution to my query. Thank you.

Below is the tables in my database:

> ```
> +table1
> -id
> -column
>
> +table2
> -id
> -table1_id
> -column
>
> +table3
> -id
> -table1_id
> -column
> ```

below is my code in the controller:

```
public function something() {
      $something_var = DB::table('table1')->leftjoin(table2, table1.id, '=', table2.table1_id)->rightjoin(table3, table1.id, '=', table3.id)->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. You would need a Model for each Table, and a relationship between them, then you'd query something like `$somethingVar = Table1::with('table2s.table3s')->paginate(10)` (although pagination doesn't work so well with relationships, you should probably stick with `join` logic for that)

Comment: What Tim sais is very important. And as a sidenote, since you say "I created a joining table in my controller but, it's to long", I would like to advice you to write every `->` and `::` with the function behind it on a new line. Even with the proper relationship setup, your queries will get large. Look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264764/multiple-category-id-wise-show-product-in-laravel-9/74265085#74265085 as an example of how to make the code more readable